# Can instrumentTest source sets have own assets?

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing

I need instrumentTest build to have it's own assets.

Source set structure

```
├── build.gradle
├── libs
└── src
    ├── instrumentTest
    │   ├── assets
    │   └── java
    └── main
        ├── AndroidManifest.xml
        ├── assets
        ├── java
        └── res
```

What have I tried

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.2'

    // There were no soureSets in my project in the first place
    // I have added sourceSets for instrumentTest, but that made no difference
    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest {
            java.srcDir 'src/instrumentTest/java'
            assets.srcDir 'src/instrumentTest/assets'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            runProguard false
        }

        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Running

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```

Fails with

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: busybox
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
```

At line

```
final InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("busybox");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instrumentTest assets are packaged as part of the instrumentation test, not the application being tested - you are probably using the target application's context instead of the instrumentation context, which is why it can't find the asset.

You can get the instrumentation context using getInstrumentation().getContext() in any [InstrumentationTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html).

You should be able to read your instrumentTest assets by obtaining an AssetManager with getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().